# is there a character limit for hash keys?

Tags: ruby

The code below fails on repl.it and codeacademy labs, but when I choose a key length < 8, it works. Neither key length fails in irb.

Is this just a problem with the web REPLs, or is there a real limitation to the length of a key?

```
class Fixnum

    def in_words
        words =
        {
           100000000 => "trillion"
        }
        puts words[self]
    end

end

100000000.in_words
```

Comment: Is `100000000` a trillion? And BTW, it's better practice to write big numbers with `_`: `1_000_000_000_000` is a trillion, and with it you had a problem, right?

Comment: yes, it's far less than a trillion. Any more digits, including underscores, and it errored out

Comment: @dwilbank what REPL are you using?  IRB works fine with Ruby 2.0.0-p247 and IRB version irb 0.9.6(09/06/30), as does Pry version 0.9.12.2 on Ruby 2.0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In console all is right, so I believe it's repl problem

```
2.0.0p247 :001 > words = {100000000 => "trillion"}
 => {100000000=>"trillion"} 
2.0.0p247 :002 > words[100000000]
 => "trillion"
```

In fact hashes do not use keys as is, but their hash sum

```
2.0.0p247 :011 > 100000000.hash
 => -2175987708688930977 
2.0.0p247 :012 > 1.hash
 => 4338493366955093097
```

So all keys have same length in this sense.

Comment: Thanks. And oh great. Now I have to find another REPL.